# How to keep values from reverting back to default during update in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo document with some default behavior

```
var thingSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    things:
        first: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        second: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
); 

var myThings = mongoose.model('Things', thingsSchema);
```

If I then update first

```
myThings.update({things: {first: true}});
```

and output `Things`

```
Things.find(function(err, things){
     console.log(things) // {things: {first: true}, {second: false}}
});
```

and I then update the second value

```
myThings.update({things: {second: true}});
```

I get `{things: {first: false}, {second: true}}` when I output again, instead of the desired `{things: {first: true}, {second: true}}`.

Without having to pass both `first` and `second` values to `update` each time, how can I keep my model from reverting back to its default behavior?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you're seeing.  Can you edit your question to include actual code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: "how can I keep my model from reverting back to its default behavior", well, if it is not the default behavior, do not define at as the default value...